# How to solve this error in opencart?

Tags: opencart

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /home/giftstore/public_html/myonlinegiftstore/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php on line 152**

Comment: What are you trying to do when you receive that error? Just load a page? Do you get it every time? Do you have much custom development or plugins loaded?

Answer (score 0):

This is server problem. Increase the memory size.  Please contact to your server provider or if it is on local server then increase your memory limit from php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase following thing in `php.ini`

1. memory_limit increase to **512M**
2. post_max_size increase to **512M**
3. max_execution_time to **1800**